# Keep a unified time on a P2P network

Tags: p2p, lazarus, freepascal

Im developing a P2P network, using Synapse for lazarus. I did almost everything, but im unable to find a way to keep a "global" time inside the network, since each user have its own local time (and timestamp) so when they sent a message to the network, i cant imagine how that message could contain a date/time format that every peer could understand. Any idea how it could be implemented?

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time

Comment: http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/PascalTZ

Comment: Do you just need a common understanding of time independent of timezones or do you need their clocks to be synchronized? Or what exactly is the purpose of time-keeping (e.g. establishing some ordering of events?)

Comment: Yes, i need order the events and keep track of the time each one happens, but in a way every member knows when exactly happened.

Comment: Any reliable(s) server(s) which offers time or timestamp info via simple http request?